# How to limit the user can only play the guessing game only for 5 times but it is not the user attempts on guessing in Java?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
 package playthegame;


import java.util.*;
public class PlayTheGame {
public static void main(String[] args) {

     Random randomNumber = new Random();
    int numberToGuess;
    int numberOfTries;
    int numberOfLimit = 5;
    int userInput;

    ArrayList<Integer> theInputs = new ArrayList();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int start = 0;
    boolean winTracker = false;
    int temp;

    while (0 == start) {
        numberToGuess = randomNumber.nextInt(10);
        userInput = 0;
        numberOfTries = 0;
        System.out.println("Please guess the number between 1 and 10: ");
        while (numberToGuess != userInput && numberOfTries < numberOfLimit) {

            userInput = in.nextInt();
            temp = userInput;
            numberOfTries++;

            if (userInput == numberToGuess) {
                theInputs.add(userInput);
                System.out.println("You win!\n");
                System.out.println("The guess number is " + numberToGuess+"\n");
                System.out.println("It takes a total of " + numberOfTries + " guesses\n");
                System.out.println("These are the guesses number : " + theInputs+"\n");
                theInputs.clear();
            } else if (userInput < numberToGuess) {
                theInputs.add(userInput);
                System.out.println("Oppss, The number is too small\n");
                System.out.println("Try next guess: \n");
            } else if (userInput > numberToGuess) {
                theInputs.add(userInput);
                System.out.println("Oppss, The number is too High\n");
                System.out.println("Try next guess: \n");
            }
        }

        if (numberToGuess != userInput) {
            System.out.println("==============================================================");
            System.out.println("Oppss..You are out of Guess Limitation!The correct number is: " + numberToGuess);
        }

    }



}

}
```

How to limit the user can only play the guessing game only for 5 times in Java if the user whether have won or lost playing the game?

is there any possibility to set the user only play for 5 times?anyone, please help

Comment: Get rid of that `while (0 == start)` and you should be pretty much good to go.

Comment: You need to count guess attempts.

Comment: this [similar post on CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39938/guessing-a-unique-4-random-digits-number) will help you

Comment: thanks, but what I mean is how to set the game can only be played for five times only not the user guess?

Comment: Put the code together in one box, the gap is confusing. Can't edit it myself as an edit is pending.

Comment: Hi Juru, I have combined them all together, can you help me to set it up?

Answer (score 0):

You are in an endless loop with the

```
while(0 == start)
```

statement because the start variable is never reassigned to another value after assigning zero to it. You can just remove that loop or add a

```
start = 1;
```

statement once the user has 5 tries.

Comment: Hi Juru I have combined them all together, can you help me to set it up?because I'm still confused on how to do that. Thanks

Comment: Just remove the while(0 == start) { line to begin with, don't forget the ending bracket } after all "else if" statements.